# Manipulate strings obtained from find command in bash script before dumping to file

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, find

I am using the find command in a shell (bash) script to obtain a list of files matching a pattern and dump those filesnames to a text file.

```
find ./ -type f -name *.txt >> files.list
```

Which produces a file containing

```
helloworld.txt
letter.txt
document-1.txt
document-1.backup.txt
```

etc.

The find command isn't that important. The one I am actually using contains regex-es, and produces a sensible list of matching files to be used as input file to a program.

I want to tag each filename with a flag to mark whether it is a `Type A` file or a `Type B` file. ie, I want the output file `files.list` to look like this

```
helloworld.txt type=A
letter.txt type=A
document-1.txt type=B
document-1.backup.txt type=B
```

if `helloworld` and `letter` are `Type A` files, and `document-1` is a `Type B` file.

I thought perhaps I could write a `files.list.tmp` file first, and then read it back in using another bash script processing it line by line... But that would make additional file and I don't really want to do that.

Can I use the `>>` operator to create a variable or something?

I'm not really sure what I should do here.

By the way, when this bash script is called, it already knows whether the files matching the regex are of type A or type B, as that is given as an argument to the script.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought perhaps I could write a files.list.tmp file first, and then read it back in using another bash script processing it line by line... But that would make additional file and I don't really want to do that

You can avoid creating temporary file by using [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
./ascript.sh < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt')
```

And make your script read file names line by line.

Comment: What does this do / how does it work? There are 2 `<` operators and my origional find command in parentheses - how should I interpret that.

Comment: I've added a link in my answer that explains it in detail. In short *Process substitution* avoids creation of temporary file by using inout/output from a process.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe through the *case* that contains the choices:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | while read f; do type=UNKNOWN; case $f in *hello*) type=A;; *letter*) type=A;; *document*) type=B;; esac; echo $f type=$type; done
```

In the code above the choices are as follows

- *hello*: type=A
- *letter*: type=A
- *document*: type=B
- default: type=UNKNOWN

You can add as many **PATTERN*) type=TYPE;;* entries as you wish. Given your files the output is:

```
./document-1.backup.txt type=B
./document-1.txt type=B
./letter.txt type=A
./helloworld.txt type=A
```

Answer (score 0):

> By the way, when this bash script is called, it already knows whether the files matching the regex are of type A or type B, as that is given as an argument to the script.

So, as your `find` command dumps only filenames of one given type per call, it suffices to append the `type=…` tag to each output line; this can be done with `sed`, e. g.:

```
find ./ -type f -name *.txt | sed "s/$/ type=$type/" >>files.list
```